# KeyListener ignored

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to make simple program, exercise actually - its description is included in attached code. My trouble is that `keyPressed()` method is completely ignored. Please take a look if possible and provide me with some hints on what I am doing wrong.

### `class exercise_chapter10_5`

```
/*
 White a program that creates a window with a menu bar. The menu bar     should have
 a single menu that has 10 menu items with text: 0, 1, . . . , 9,     respectively. When a user
 selects a number from the menu bar, the corresponding number should be     displayed
 inside the panel of the window. Once finished, add a key listener. When     a user types
 a digit between 0 and 9, the digit should be displayed in the window.     Create an array
 to store the menu items.
 */
package exercise;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class exercise_chapter10_5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    MyPanel p;

    public MyFrame() {
        setSize(300, 300);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(bar);

        //a window with a menu bar
        JMenu numbers = new JMenu(" Numbers ");
        bar.add(numbers);

        // Create an array to store the menu items
        ArrayList<JMenuItem> menuitems = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            menuitems.add(new JMenuItem(i + ""));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < menuitems.size(); i++) {
            numbers.add(menuitems.get(i));

        }

        // add action listener for every menu item
        for (int i = 0; i < menuitems.size(); i++) {
            menuitems.get(i).addActionListener(new NumberListener(i));
        }

        p = new MyPanel();
        add(p);
    
    }

    class NumberListener implements ActionListener {

    private int number;

    public NumberListener(int num) {
        this.number = num;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        p.changeNumber(number);
    }
}
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int number;

    public void changeNumber(int num) {
        this.number = num;
        repaint();
    }

    public MyPanel()  {

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                  
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             
            changeNumber((e.getKeyChar() - '0'));
            
            //System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
            System.out.println("In Panel the number typed is: " + number);
            repaint();
        }
    });
    
    System.out.println("Panel was born");
    

     addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                System.out.println("current number is: " + number);
                repaint();
            }
            if (e.getButton() == 3) {// right button was pressed
                System.out.println("Right mouse button was pressed");
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
}

    public void showMessage(String s, Graphics2D g2) {
        Font myFont = new Font(" SansSerif ", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 40);
        g2.setFont(myFont);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        Rectangle2D textBox = myFont.getStringBounds(s, g2.getFontRenderContext());
        g2.drawString(s, (int) (getWidth() / 2 - textBox.getWidth() / 2), (int) (getHeight() / 2 - textBox.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        showMessage(Integer.toString(number), g2);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add that listener to say your button, menu etc. Where have you added it?

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: BTW  - a component needs to be both focusable and in focus for `KeyListener` to fire events.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints. What worked for me here is that I had to call setFocusable(true) method within JPanel constructor first.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private int number;

public void changeNumber(int num) {
    this.number = num;
    repaint();
}

public MyPanel()  {

    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            changeNumber((e.getKeyChar() - '0'));

            //System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
            System.out.println("In Panel the number typed is: " + number);
            repaint();
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Panel was born");


     addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                System.out.println("current number is: " + number);
                repaint();
            }
            if (e.getButton() == 3) {// right button was pressed
                System.out.println("Right mouse button was pressed");
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As suggested [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), `requestFocusInWindow()` " is preferred to the `requestFocus()` method, which is platform-dependent."

Comment: Well, sorry, but requestFocusInWindow() does not work for me. Only setFocusable(true) worked. I don't know the reason.

Comment: *"`requestFocusInWindow()` does not work for me. Only `setFocusable(true)` worked"*  `<head-desk/>`  @trashgod meant to use them both!  That your key listener is being heard now, is the random chance of that component having the current input focus.  Add some other components and that will likely change.